# Wait for button click to find find element - VueJS/Jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I am writing a test to see if a modal window pops up after a button click, and not sure proper way how to tell the test to wait for the click.

So for example, say I have a modal window that displays on click of the image as follows:

***CALENDAR.VUE***

```
<template>

   <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
       <b-img ref='cal-modal' id='cal-modal' class="cal-icon" @click="displayCal" v-b-modal.date-time-modal src="/static/img/ico.png"></b-img>
    </div>

    <b-modal id="date-time-modal" ref="date-time-modal" hide-footer title="Modal Title">
      <div class="d-block text-center">
         <p>This is a modal window</p>    
      </div>
    </b-modal>

</template>
```

***CALENDAR.SPEC.JS***

```
import {createLocalVue, mount} from "@vue/test-utils";
import Calendar from '@/components/Calendar.vue'
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(BootstrapVue)


  it('display cal', () => {
      const wrapper = mount(Calendar, {localVue});
      wrapper
          .find('#cal-modal')
          .trigger('click')
  })
```

What is the best way to wait for the "Click" event to happen before looking for the

Comment: Think this might be what you are looking for: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks

Comment: Interesting! Not quite what I was looking for but helps for future things. Thank you

Comment: No problem, but due think it can solve your problem as you can fast forward time within the test, thus jump, say 5 seconds, and the modal will be rendered (though a matter of ms actually has passed)